# How to use channel api for chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-chrome-app, channel-api

I am trying to create an application where I need to receive url information from Google app engine server(python) to a client (chrome app) through channel api.

I found this example (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/appengine-channelapi) but it is complicated for me.

can anyone suggest any other way or explain me with a simple example

Comment: Not unless you explain which specific parts are unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure if this example is correct though; it makes more sense to use a sandbox instead of a webview.

Comment: I am able to implement similar to above example. I will also look into sandbox. Thank you !!